# Toggling Views EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, uiview

I have a UIView in my class (besides the original view) made in interface builder.

```
@interface TimeLineGrid : UIViewController {

UIView *toggleView;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *toggleView;
```

I have synthesized it as well. I have implemented a swipe gesture so that when swiped up, the toggle view is added and when swiped down the toggle view is removed.

```
-(void)swipedUp {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0f];

    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:NO];

    [self.view addSubview:self.toggleView];

    [UIView commitAnimations];



}

-(void)swipedDown {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0f];

    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:NO];

    [self.toggleView removeFromSuperview];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

It works fine when I swipe up once and when I swipe down after that. But when i swipe up once again, it crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I know this has something to do with the retain count increasing when I addSubview and reducing when I removeSubview. Can someone shed more light on this? How do I achieve this toggle?

EDIT:
My view hierarchy is as follows:

```
->UIView (toggleView)
->UIView (mainView to which toggleView is being added)
 -->UIToolBar
```

Comment: You seem to be adding and removing the view fine. Where do you create and assign the view to toggleView?

Comment: Enable "Run Static Analyser" in the build settings of your target to see where you do memory management the wrong way.

Comment: @Dancreek: It's made in interface builder. I just connected the view to the toggleView outlet.

Comment: In that case the view should already be part of your view heiarchy.  You shouldn't need to add and remove it.  Have you tried just toggeling the `hidden` property or setting the `alpha` to 0.0?

Comment: Animation by "hidden" or "alpha" would be more suitable in your case as suggested by @Dancreek .

Comment: @Dancreek : It's not been added as a subview to the mainView yet. I have edited the question. @Jhaliya: I want to know how to do it without hiding the views.  Is there a way?

Comment: But this should work shouldn't it? As the property is retained, so when the view is created from the nib, it's retain count goes up once, then when it's added it goes up again (2), then when it's removed it goes to 1, and so the view should still be in memory.

Comment: @Jonathan It does work for the first time (one view addition and then removal). But after that when I try to add the view again it gives an exception.

Comment: @HG's I know but after it has been removed it should have a retain count of 1. So when you go backup add the divvies again the toggle view shouldn't have been dealloced and you shouldn't get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. (though it would be easier to use the hidden or alpha property if the view, I'd like to know why this way doesnt work)

Comment: @Jonathan Thats what even I thought but I encountered a strange behavior. I put two NSLogs. One before removing subview which says "Gonna Remove Toggle View" and one after saying "Removed Toggle View". When I swipe down the first time, the result I get is as follows : "Gonna Remove Toggle View" "Gonna Remove Toggle View" "Removed Toggle View" "Removed Toggle View". So it is getting removed twice but how, that's what im not able to understand.

Comment: @HG's try removing the animation code, see if it just works. I've never used `setAnimationTransition:forView:cache` and I'm not sure what exactly it does, but likely because the remove statement is in the animation section it is being called multiple times over the 2 seconds. Also it's better o use blocks for animation now, (that is if your not targeting old iOSes)

Comment: @Jonathan I removed animation and tried. It's still being called twice. The way its being called is also strange. "Gonna Remove Toggle View" is being executed first twice and then the "Removed Toggle View" comes. That's really strange.

Comment: @HG's on more of a limb now, maybe it's the swipe gesture, try adding a button or something. It's more likely something to do with memory, but to me the releases and retains add up.

Comment: @Jonathan Tried that. No luck.

Comment: If your swipe gesture is being triggered twice, then that's the most probable source of the problem.  Post the code that sets up the swipe gesture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, the view is being released when you call `[self.toggleView removeFromSuperview];`. I recommend that you restructure your code a little.

Since you are creating the view in IB, declare it in the header file as

```
IBOutlet UIView *toggleView;
```

Do **not** include the property call or the synthesize. Since you are not setting or getting the toggleView, just refer to it by the pointer.

In the implementation, set the pointer to `nil` in `viewDidUnload` and release it in `dealloc`. Then, adjust your toggle methods as follows:

```
-(void)swipedUp {
    if (![toggleView superview]) {

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0f];

        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:NO];

        [self.view addSubview:toggleView];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

-(void)swipedDown {

    if ([toggleView superview]) {

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0f];

        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:NO];

        [toggleView removeFromSuperview];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Here, the `if` clause will catch the event that the user swipes up twice in a row and not respond to the second swipe. Notice also that this uses `toggleView` in place of `self.toggleView`.

This should resolve the problem.

Comment: @HG's You're mst welcome. Glad it worked. Don't forget to award the bounty before it expires :-)

Comment: Oh sorry forgot bout that. Did it now. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Could you please apply such changes and tell which UIView is exactly has proble.

1. Open XCode/Product/Edit Scheme...
2. Move to Environment Variables and then click the plus to add variable
3. Add variable NSZombieEnables - value: YES
4. Add variable MallocStackLoggingNoCompact  - value: 1

After starting the application, you will see, which exactly object was disposed, when you call it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making the views you want to show/hide, be *both* subviews of a container view. Then, in your animation block you first remove a view that dissapears and add the view that you want to show. For example:

```
@interface TimeLineGrid : UIViewController {
    // declare the views you want to flip between
    UIView *mainView;
    UIView *toggleView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *mainView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *toggleView;
```

In your implementation:

```
// self.view is the container view (an instance of UIView).
// Initially, self.mainView is a subview of self.view

-(void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView withAnimation:(UIViewAnimationTransition)animation {

    if ([toView superview]) {
        // toView already shown
        return;
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0f];

    [UIView setAnimationTransition:animation forView:self.view cache:NO];

    [self.view removeFromSuperview:fromView];
    [self.view addSubview:toView];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

-(void)swipedUp {
    [self transitionFromView:self.mainView 
                      toView:self.toggleView 
               withAnimation:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft];
}

-(void)swipedDown {
    [self transitionFromView:self.toggleView 
                      toView:self.mainView 
               withAnimation:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight];
}
```

Note however, that use of the method `setAnimationTransition:forView:cache:` is now discouraged. Apple recommends using the UIView `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` method (see the [UIView reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I have made an application containing UITabbar and I got the same behavior but with UIButton.

That happens when you dont release the object on which you call `removeFromSuperview`, I have the same effect when I was removing a UIButton from my viewControllers view.

In my case I could still see the button and if I click on it, I get an exception like unrecognized selector send to object of type NSCFString.

But if I change the tab then return to my view controller where the button was showing previously after removing it from my view, then it was gone.

So my conclusion is that if you dont release the object on which your are calling `removeFromSuperview` then the app will show some unexpected behavior if you have the object as an instance variable of your class and added it to the view programmatically by  `addSubView` method.

What are your options:-

1. You can call `removeFromSuperview` on a uiview or its subclass objects and call release on it or make it nil.
2. You can hide or unhide those objects using `hidden` property instead of removing them from superview.
3. (I haven't tried it exactly)You can create a `UIView` object in your class implementation and then add it as a `subview` and then assign it to your instance variable your class using dot operator and then release the previously created `UIView` object.

I dont know how my answer might help you but I think its good to share your experience with others.